# rank() function SQL

Tags: mysql, rank

I want to rank the following Scores table where same scores will have same rank.

```
+----+-------+
| Id | Score |
+----+-------+
| 1  | 3.50  |
| 2  | 4.00  |
| 3  | 4.00  |
| 4  | 3.50  |
+----+-------+
```

Can someone help why is the following query throwing a syntax error ? Also, is the logic incorrect?

Code:

```
select Score, RANK() OVER (order by Score desc) as rank
from Scores
order by Score desc;
```

Error message:

```
Line 1: SyntaxError: near '(order by Score desc) as rank
from Scores
order by Score desc'
```

Comment: MYSQL doesnt support window functions yet

Comment: Aah - that explains it. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

E.g.: (And assuming you want ranks of 1 and 2 rather than 1 and 3)

```
SELECT x.*
     , CASE WHEN @prev = score THEN @i:=@i ELSE @i:=@i+1 END rank
     , @prev:=score 
  FROM my_table x
     , (SELECT @prev:=null,@i:=0) vars 
 ORDER 
    BY score DESC
     , id;
```

For sports ranking, you can do this:

```
SELECT a.*
     , FIND_IN_SET(score,
                    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(score ORDER BY score DESC) 
                         -- inclusion of DISTINCT here will output as above
                       FROM my_table)
                   ) x 
  FROM my_table a;
```

But there are certain caveats associated with this solution

Comment: I think `cross join` will be more better than `,`.

Comment: @Forward. No, it's the same.

Comment: Haters gonna hate